# SQL UPDATE with SELECT Issue. SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my SQL. I would like to use a select to make an update, but so far I haven't been able to acomplish it. I would really apreciate if anyone could please help me. I'm quite new at MySQL. THe query in question is this:

```
UPDATE
    pac
SET 
    pac.pac_spc_id = dtn_atual.spc_id
FROM 
    pac_paciente pac
INNER JOIN (    SELECT 
                    dtn.dtn_pac_id,
                    spc_id
                FROM  `pac_destino` dtn
                INNER JOIN ( select 
                                 des.dtn_pac_id, 
                                 MAX(CONCAT(des.dtn_data, des.dtn_seq)) AS datamax  
                            FROM pac_destino des
                            GROUP BY des.`dtn_pac_id`
                           ) AS d1 ON d1.dtn_pac_id = dtn.dtn_pac_id
                        AND d1.datamax = CONCAT(dtn.dtn_data, dtn.dtn_seq)
                LEFT JOIN pac_classdestino c1 ON c1.cdo_id = dtn.dtn_cdo_id
                LEFT JOIN pac_statuspaciente spc ON spc.spc_id = c1.cdo_spc_id
                ) AS dtn_atual on dtn_atual.dtn_pac_id = pac.`pac_id`
```

The error generated is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'FROM pac_paciente pac INNER JOIN (    SELECT  
   dtn.dtn_pac_id, spc_id
   ' at line 5
```

Comment: So, you say there's a syntax error?  Care to share the *exact* error with us?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing, but your query is wrong.  UPDATE syntax is `UPDATE tablename SET field=value WHERE field=value`

Comment: You can add queries to the top of an update statement by wrapping them in brackets and assigning an alias.  The MySQL manual may help you out in order to this as it is the same methodology as doing a multi-table update: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html